# Как в свой плагин WordPress добавить вторую страницу?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я написал плагин, все работает, но нужно создать вторую административную страницу для него, что бы после обработки формы переходить на нее.На Первой странице форма, на фоторой оработчик этой формы с выводом информации. Не могу найти как ее нужно подключить внутри плагина, подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

Comment: А в чем проблема в создании именно второй административной страницы? Создайте ее так же как и первую.

Comment: в этом и вопрос, при создании второй страницы внутри плагина она не подключается, как административная страница плагина, то есть у нее нее нет панелей админки, как чистая html страница. И внутри этого файла не работают все функции, если не подключать внутри нее отдельно вордпресс.

Comment: Так может код покажете? Или будем гадать что же могло пойти не так?

Comment: я разобрался, там ниже есть ответ, просто я пытался сделать отдельной страницей, в итоге добавил еще один add_submenu_page() после основного. Но спасибо за попытку помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Изпользуйте `add_submenu_page`

add_menu_page(
        'Parrent',
        'Parrent title',
        'manage_options',
        URL.'admin/index.php',
        '',
        plugins_url( 'plugin-folder/admin/images/logo.svg' )
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        URL.'admin/index.php',
        'Parrent',
        'Parrent data',
        'manage_options',
        'settings-form',
        'some_settings'
    );
```

Comment: Именно такой вариант я и реализовал, спасибо!